# Does order persist when using subqueries?

Tags: sql

I am using a hierarchical query, which has an interesting order siblings clause available, so I can sort my results from a child node to it's ancestor node. However, if I want to do this operation, and then select one of these as a final answer, I would like to take the first result in the order they are in - to do this, I am doing a row_number() over partition query - can I assume that the order siblings from the subquery will persist when doing my row_number() so that row_number() = 1 would be the first result as defined by order siblings?

Comment: You need to supply your current query and some sample data with the expected output. Also which DBMS do you use? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think when trying to create an example, I found what I need to do it, the issue is I have data that has converted it's unique key (The name is in the data below just for ease of discussion). Other data can then use that unique key - so I only have whether it is a starting or ending transition, and the time of the transition, so I have used this query with the "root" node being the changes later in time


PREVID NEWID NAME TRANSYEAR START END
1 2 Adam 1951 1 0
3 4 Barry 1952 1 0
2 3 Adam 1953 0 1
4 2 Barry 1953 0 0
2 1 Barry 1954 0 1
.
5 2 Charlie 1955 1 1